# swift UICollectionView only showing black screen

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

my UICollection view is displaying only black screen.. and i cant find the cell inside it..

in storyboard i layout like this:
[image]

in simulator it shows :

[image]

Comment: Have you implemented the delegate and the datasource in the viewcontroller?

Comment: can you add in some code you had done so far

Comment: Looks like there is not cell inside. Show your code.

Answer (score 4):

The default `backgroundColor` of `UICollectionView` is "Black".
Just set the `backgroundColor` to White

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you set the cell's identifier in the nib or storyboard, don't register the nib/class in the collection view controller. Do one or the other, but not both.